# SpringBoot JdbcTemplate with SQL Server: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, spring-data, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a SpringBoot app. that uses JdbcTemplate to connect to a SQL Server DB, using this syntax:

```
int numOfRowsAffected = remoteJdbcTemplate.update(
        "insert into dbo.[ATRESMEDIA Resource Time Registr_]  " +
        "( [Entry No_], [Record ID], [Posting Date], [Resource No_], [Job No_], [Work Type], [Quantity], [Unit of Measure], [Description], [Company Name], [Created Date-Time], [Status] ) " +
                " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);",

                atresMediaTimeRegistr.getEntryNo(),
                "Record ID",
                atresMediaTimeRegistr.getPostingDate(),
                atresMediaTimeRegistr.getResourceNo(),
                atresMediaTimeRegistr.getJobNo(),
                atresMediaTimeRegistr.getWorkType(),
                atresMediaTimeRegistr.getQuantity(),
                atresMediaTimeRegistr.getUnitOfMeasure(),
                atresMediaTimeRegistr.getDescription(),
                atresMediaTimeRegistr.getCompanyName(),
                atresMediaTimeRegistr.getCreatedDate(),
                1);
```

where `[Record ID]` is a `varbinary` type, but I got this error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into dbo.[ATRESMEDIA Resource Time Registr_]  ( [Entry No_], [Record ID], [Posting Date], [Resource No_], [Job No_], [Work Type], [Quantity], [Unit of Measure], [Description], [Company Name], [Created Date-Time], [Status] )  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);]; SQL state [S0003]; error code [257]; Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an answer in you question: `...Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary is not allowed...` You are trying to pass a string as a varbinary. First you must do something like this 
`byte[] varBinary = "record_ID".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`
And then put it into jdbcTemplate as a Record_ID parameter.
Good luck, hope it'll help!